# Normalize the input to dl model and then un-normalize the predicted values

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks

Here is a simple case of my problem. I want to predict the temperature for 5 meter for next days. I am using two features. Temperature and humidity ( I assumed that I have the humidity for tomorrow). So, I have a problem with normalization.

here is a type of my data set. The training data is for 10 days. So, what is the the best way to normalize the data? in my model, the predicted value is also in range (0-1), and how can I un-normalized the predicted value? Can you help me with that? Thank you.

```
temperature_train = np.random.randint(3, size = (5, 24*10))
humidity_train    = np.random.randint(3, size = (5, 24*10))

humidity_test    = np.random.randint(3,     size = (5, 24))
```

Comment: Why is the predicted value in range 0-1?

Comment: @gunes: Sorry for the delay. This is one of my big problem. The model which I am using is the conditional variational autoencoder and when I train the model, if I do not normalize the predict values (labels), my loss goes to nan values. So I have to normalize them.

Comment: The predicted value should be unnormalized by applying the inverse of the transform you used while normalizing.